# Are you able to use weight generated by a different framework for transfer learning in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I made a classifier AI that classifies images into 4 classes, it is trained with a measly 81 images and its accuracy is at a meager ~60%. Then i found another project that is somewhat similar to what im doing (we basically train on the same kind of images). I was thinking if i could try to use the weights generated on that specific model and transfer learn it to mine.

Im very new to this field so i do not know if weights can just be used interoperably from framework to framework. I made my program in tensorflow Keras. And it looks like the author of the project is using a different framework: torch.

I downloaded the weights that the other project generated and it looks like this:

[image]

It looked to be training checkpoints. Is it possible to import this into tensorflow keras?

Comment: maybe torch 2 onnx, and onnx to tensorflow. but best to use one framework, maybe only torch.